# What is Google Cloud's Cloud Setup Host Project?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am learning about Google Cloud.
We have created a Google Cloud organization using Cloud Identity.

At that time, a project called Cloud Setup Host Project was created. The project ID is `cs-host-XXXXXXXXXXX`, which does not seem to be a normal project.

Please tell me what this project is for, when this project was created, and whether I can delete this project.

`"IAM and Management">"Identity and Organization">"Go to Checklist"`

STEP 1 through STEP 4 have been performed.

Comment: Did you figure it out? This page is the only Google result when I search for "Cloud Setup Host Project" 